# Performance difference between source-code targeted at different Java versions?

Tags: java

I have a 1.5 compatible Java source which will run solely on 1.8 VM and wondering whether it would be beneficial to target 1.8 during compilation instead of an older version.

Would there be any performance difference between 1.5 vs 1.8? 
Is there any relevant documentation or change-logs available which I could take a look at??

Comment: Are you asking whether Java 8 class files will be faster than Java 5 class files on a Java 8 JVM, or whether Java 8 class files on a Java 8 JVM are faster than Java 5 class files on a Java 5 JVM?

Comment: @meriton the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `javac` does almost no optimisation.  The main optimisation it does is constant inlining and it has always done this.

The difference is entirely in the JVM.  In Java 8 you have more options to write the same code, which means you can re-write code to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

Since the compiled Java code you are referring to is the Java Byte code, running your old application with a new JVM version (1.8) should improve the performance of your application without the need of a recompilation of the byte code.

You can have a look at the Oracle official documentation regarding [JDK 8 performance improvement](https://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/learn_more_about_performance_and) to understand whats changed.

Comment: But would the bytecode generated for newer targets be any "better"? I  decompiled a few classes and there is definitely a difference between the bytecode when targeting 1.5 vs 1.8.
I've looked at the JDK chnagelogs, but was hopping there would a summarized version somewhere specific to performance related changes in javac if such exists.

Comment: It should not make much difference, there could be a potential difference but not so much, maybe even not noticeable. Different it would be if you will change the code to take advantage of the new optimised data structure, etc ...

Comment: It might, in future, in some small ways, but not many.  For example, Java 9 is expected to change the way string concatenation is compiled to use invokedynamic, which is only available when targeting Java 7 and above.

Answer (score 1):

I usually set the compilation to 1.7. The new lambda syntax among other features of java 8 is nice to have, but I run into far less compatibility issues with java 7, and it's what I'm used to.

If you use the VM to work in yourself, and you know you don't have rely on frameworks that will end up with issues, by all means start with java 8.
You can also check the official documentation, but Wikipedia actually provides a nice change log imo:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Answer (score 1):

I found [this Oracle source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) that discusses the compatibility of Java 7 with earlier versions. It mentions only the `invokedynamic` bytecode as a (bytecode) difference between version 7 and 6. Since the bytecode doesn't really change much, the effects of version 5 bytecode vs. version 8 bytecode on *performance* are negligible.

Comment: The `invokedynamic` was (IIRC) the only *real* (or at least: the only significant) change to the bytecode since the JVM was introduced, so it's definitely worth mentioning. But I'm not sure what the implications on performance are. You mentioned that they are "negligible", but ... where will be performance differences *at all*, and how large will they be?

Comment: According to [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2860079/scripting-jvm-languages/invokedynamic-101.html) the reason for `invokedynamic` actually was performance. Just not Java performance, but other dynamic languages that run on the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Except performance you should consider the thousand bug fixes which have been fixed since 1.5

There are also new APIs on 1.8 such as javafx , NIO , lambas.

Oracle announced that swing will not update anymore , so if your application has GUI you should consider to start looking for porting to javafx.

In oracle site btw when you download an new jdk there is also a link to it's changelog

Comment: Good point about bug fixes but I am curios more about performance difference between bytecode generated for different targets.
The application has no GUI.

Comment: Thre is a new garbage collector more efficient starting from java 1.6 . Hotspot has been rewritten for x64 as well . Other info are I guess more oracle's internally secrets and you can only compare by doing some tests on your own